# Is $\oplus$ the only monoidal structure on the simplex category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, simplicial-stuff, monoidal-categories

Simplicial sets are presheaves on the simplex category $\Delta$, while  augmented simplicial sets are presheaves on $\Delta_+$, the augmented  simplex category. Because Day convolution allows us to lift monoidal structures on a category $\mathcal{C}$ to its category of presheaves $\mathrm{Sets}^{\Delta^\circ}$, it is therefore of interest to find monoidal structures on $\Delta$ and $\Delta_+$, as these then provide "natural" monoidal structures on simplicial sets.

The only monoidal structure I know of is the ordinal sum of $\Delta_+$ (which is not braided), whose Day convolution gives the join of simplicial sets, and whose internal hom is given by
$$[X,Y]_n=\mathrm{hom}_{\mathrm{Sets}^{\Delta^\circ_+}}(X,\mathrm{Dec}^{n+1}Y)$$

Is this the only monoidal structure on $\Delta_+$? If not, what other monoidal structures are there on $\Delta_+$, and what are there on $\Delta$?

Comment: Crossposted: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4229440/classification-of-monoidal-structures-on-the-simplex-category)

Comment: I think this more likely to get an answer here than at m.se. Also, note that one day is not really enough time to wait before crossposting, given the international nature of the site. Best to wait a few days at minimum.

Comment: Cartesian product of ordered sets (using lexicographic order) gives another monoidal structure.

Comment: @DavidRoberts My apologies, I'll wait longer before crossposting from now on.

Comment: @TylerLawson I can't believe I thought of $\oplus$, but not of $\times$! Thank you.

Comment: @Sofia not a problem! It's sometimes not obvious how the two sites operate side-by-side.

Comment: The cartesian product of simplicial sets do not come from a monoidal structure on $\Delta$ : The product of two representable isn't representable.

Comment: @SimonHenry Oh, right. Do you know what the Day convolution of the "fake $\times$" above gives?

Comment: I don't think this can be made into a functor. Does it ?

Comment: @SimonHenry Oh, right! Products under the lexicographic order are not functorial with respect to order preserving maps.

Comment: Ah, that's my fault. I wasn't careful enough checking and I didn't account for all maps in the simplex category. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Do the maps $\left[n\right] \times \left[m\right] \to \left[nm\right],\ \left(i,j\right) \mapsto \left(i-1\right)m+j$ (where $\left[k\right] := \left\{1,2,\ldots,k\right\}$) create a monoidal structure? (The question is not rhetorical; I don't remember all the axioms and don't have enough intuition to just handwave them away.)

Comment: Actually, no, they don't, unless we replace $\Delta$ by the strictly order-preserving subcategory. Otherwise, a product of two order-preserving maps can fail to be order-preserving.

Comment: Since all isomorphisms are identities you should first wonder about monoid structures on non negative integers

Comment: How does the "tropical" monoidal structure act on morphisms?

Comment: @darijgrinberg It, too, is not functorial :(

Comment: Note that in any monoidal structure, the unit object has a commutative endomorphism monoid. So in any monoidal structure on $\Delta_+$, the unit is either $[0]$ or $[-1]$.

Comment: The objects $[n]$ of $\Delta_+$ admit lots of idempotents $e$. I think that not very many of these idempotents commute with one another. But an object $[m] \otimes [n]$ has lots of commuting idempotents of the form $e \otimes 1$ and $1 \otimes e'$. This seems like a promising tension to me.

Comment: $\Delta_+$ does admit some other _non-unital_ monoidal structures. For instance, one can define $[m] \otimes [n] = [m] \oplus [k] \oplus [n]$ for some fixed $k$. When $k=1$, this can be seen as arising from [Joyal's equivalence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/classifying+topos#ForIntervals) $\Delta_+ \cong \Delta_{\bot,\top}^{op}$ between $\Delta_+$ and the opposite of the category of intervals.

Comment: One almost-trivial note: The “switched” ordinal sum gives a second monoidal structure on $\Delta_+$ — the two handednesses of ordinal sum are not isomorphic.

Comment: Here is another monoidal structure with unit $[-1]$: Define $[m] \otimes [n] = \begin{cases} [m] & [n] = [-1] \\ [n] & [m] = [-1] \\ [0] & \text{else} \end{cases}$; after imposing unitality, there is a unique way to extend this definition to morphisms, and unless I'm mistaken it works out to be (strict) monoidal.

Comment: @TimCampion: I’ve always found that monoidal structure (well, the analogous one on [sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155939/what-other-monoidal-structures-exist-on-the-category-of-sets)) difficult to grok.  The clearest description I’ve found of it is to see $A_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_k$ as the connected components of the complete $k$-partite graph on $A_1 + \cdots + A_k$; this at least makes the functoriality clearer, but and to some extent the associativity too, but the whole thing still feels a bit mysterious!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is half of a classification. Let $\otimes$ be a monoidal structure on $\Delta_+$. As I mentioned in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402257/is-oplus-the-only-monoidal-structure-on-the-simplex-category#comment1032524_402257), the monoidal unit must be $[-1]$ or $[0]$ because these are the only objects with commutative endomorphism monoids.

Suppose that the monoidal unit is $[0]$. Let us consider $[1] \otimes [1]$. We have that $[0]$ is a retract of $[1]$ in 2 ways, and as a result we obtain 4 retracts of $[1] \otimes [1]$ with support $[0] \otimes [0] = [0]$. Consider the induced linear ordering on these 4 points. We also have 4 ways that $[1] = [1] \otimes [0] = [0] \otimes [1]$ is a retract of $[1] \otimes [1]$, and from this we can deduce most of the ordering. It must have the following relations

$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} 0 \otimes 0 @>>> 0 \otimes 1\\ @VVV @VVV\\ 1 \otimes 0 @>>> 1 \otimes 1 \end{CD}$

To complete this to a linear order, without loss of generality we must have $0 \otimes 1 \leq 1 \otimes 0$. But now, one of our 4 projections onto $[1]$ is the coordinate projection onto the right column of the above square. The fact that this projection is order-preserving implies that $1 \otimes 0 = 0 \otimes 1 = 1 \otimes 1$. This contradicts the fact that the right column exhibits $[1]$ as a retract of this subset of $[1] \otimes [1]$.

Therefore the monoidal unit is not $[0]$; it must be $[-1]$.

I also think I'm ready to conjecture that $\oplus$, $\oplus^{rev}$ (as mentioned [by Peter](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402257/is-oplus-the-only-monoidal-structure-on-the-simplex-category?noredirect=1#comment1032530_402257)) and the [degenerate monoidal structure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402257/is-oplus-the-only-monoidal-structure-on-the-simplex-category?noredirect=1#comment1032531_402257) are probably the only ones. You could imagine a classification starting as follows. Consider the maps $[0] = [0] \otimes [-1] \to [0] \otimes [0]$ and $[0] = [-1] \otimes [0] \to [0] \otimes [0]$. If these are the same, then we should have the degenerate monoidal structure. If they are different, then one is less than the other, and those two cases should correspond to $\oplus$ and $\oplus^{rev}$.